# Jackson databind dataformat MismatchedInputException

Tags: java, parsing, jackson, mapping, byte

I have a CBOR encoded byte String that I want to map to a specific type I created.
Here is the CBOR message.
`8663312e308201d818584ba401022001215820e4706de318a40d0bd8648b7907b0283f7445370241ff1fdd77f08d6a598be90222582079767fbe391223f61dcd5e980133a035b4918f6f9de41b3ceb8d801860df885981830201a201f50b78203030303030303035303030303130303038303030303038303546394233344646a080a16576616c7565697465737456616c7565`.

I created my POJO class associated to the new type TypeA. This TypeA class is composed of other non generic type. I also created the getter and setter on those classes.

```
public class TypeA {
  protected String version;
  protected TypeB b;
  protected TypeC[] cs;
  protected TypeD d;
  protected String[] docTypes;
  protected String[] applicationSpecific;
}
```

I am using jackson Databind and Jackson Dataformat. Finally here is the method called to bind the byte string onto my specific class :

```
public TypeA fromCBOR(byte[] cBOR_Data) throws IOException {
    JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(TypeA.class);
    return mapper.readValue(cBOR_Data, type);
}
```

I get that error

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize value of type
> `com.example.reader.logic.models.structures.TypeA`
> from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Any help would be appreciated :).

Thank you.

Comment: If jackson interprets your input as JSON, could it be that the string you quoted is not the "pure" input into this function?

Comment: can you put a debug statement and see the actual input to the `fromCBOR` method?

Comment: Edit : Indeed It s not really the actual input I parse the byte String onto a real byte array which gives me something like that :
 �d�y�(?tE7A��w��jY��"X yv�9#��^�3�5���o��<덀`߈Y����x 0000000500001000800000805F9B34FF���evalueitestValue

Comment: Many things can go wrong depending on how you even convert your string to a byte array. The string you mentioned above looks like a hexadecimal representation of your binary input data to me. If your `String` to `byte[]` conversion handles it like converting ASCII to bytes, you'll have a big mess

Comment: even though, from what you just mentioned in the comment the byte represenation seems to have been fine, the ...00008... segment matches the bunch of 30303038 piece from your input, if said byte array is converted over to ASCII again for a debug print

Comment: I'd put into question if jackson actually understands how to deserialize the byte array itself to your object structure. Could it be that what it actually complains about is "you just gave me an array of bytes, what should I do with it?". Did you write a custom deserializer for this?

Comment: Thanks for answering me. I finally realized the issue the method i used to convert the hex string to a byte array was somehow wrong and so on.